# Get users email address using Google OpenID

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth, asp.net-4.5, google-openid

I am trying to retrieve a user's email address from Google via OpenID using DotNetOpenAuth.

My code so far correctly redirects to Google for the current user, and asks for permission for my application to read the email address.  On being diverted back to my page however, it bounces straight back to Google.  I see why this happens (because the page never enters postback state), but how do you differentiate therefore between the request and response data, so that I can correctly read the email address in the page?

**Is there a recommended/industry standard approach for this?**

I'm only just starting out with OpenID and DotNetOpenAuth but have strong ASP.NET skills, so please keep your answers clear(!)

Thanks

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ltl.Text = "Welcome " & User.Identity.Name

    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Dim openid As New OpenIdRelyingParty
        Dim req As IAuthenticationRequest = openid.CreateRequest(User.Identity.Name)
        Dim fetch As New FetchRequest
        fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email)
        fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.FullName)
        req.AddExtension(fetch)
        req.RedirectToProvider()
    Else
        Dim openid As New OpenIdRelyingParty
        Dim resp As IAuthenticationResponse = openid.GetResponse()
        If resp IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim fetch As FetchResponse = resp.GetExtension(Of FetchResponse)()
            If fetch IsNot Nothing Then
                Trace.Warn(fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email))
            Else
                Trace.Warn("fetch was Nothing")
            End If
        Else
            Trace.Warn("resp was Nothing")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you found the DotNetOpenAuth samples [available on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnoa/files/releases/v4.2/v4.2.2/)?

Here is the recommended pattern:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ltl.Text = "Welcome " & User.Identity.Name

    Dim openid As New OpenIdRelyingParty
    Dim resp As IAuthenticationResponse = openid.GetResponse()
    If resp Is Nothing Then
        Dim req As IAuthenticationRequest = openid.CreateRequest(User.Identity.Name)
        Dim fetch As New FetchRequest
        fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email)
        fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.FullName)
        req.AddExtension(fetch)
        req.RedirectToProvider()
    Else
        Dim fetch As FetchResponse = resp.GetExtension(Of FetchResponse)()
        If fetch IsNot Nothing Then
            Trace.Warn(fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email))
        Else
            Trace.Warn("fetch was Nothing")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You're correct. I'm disappointed I didn't think to just check if a response was given.

Comment: Thanks for your input Andrew.  I wasn't aware of the code samples, and these will be extremely useful if they are as succinct as your code sample above.  I did actually solve this myself yesterday, but on seeing your example I still have scope for improvement.  On another note, while trawling the web yesterday looking for code samples, I read a lot of your posts on various sites.  Thank you for your continued efforts and contribution in this area.  It makes life much easier for developers like me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking `IsPostBack` you could add a query string parameter and check for its presence.  You could either do this when the user requests to login or when the provider returns back.

This snippet below checks for the presence of a query string parameter that indicates the provider has redirected back to your page.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ltl.Text = "Welcome " & User.Identity.Name

    If Not Request.QueryString(your_parameter) Is Nothing Then
        'Read Response
        ...
    Else
        'Send Request
        Dim openid As New OpenIdRelyingParty
        Dim req As IAuthenticationRequest = openid.CreateRequest(User.Identity.Name)

        'Specify the url the provider should redirect to
        'this would be whatever url brings you to this page plus query string 
        req.AddCallbackArguments("returnUrl", your_url);
        ...
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi yes thanks for that.  That was my first thought, but I am interested to know if there's an industry standard approach to this with DotNetOpenAuth...?

Comment: there isn't a need for an artificial callback parameter